# $f:X \to Y$ a homeomorphism, prove $\forall x\in X$ $f$ from $X \setminus \lbrace x\rbrace$ to $Y \setminus \lbrace f(x) \rbrace$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

> let $f:X \to Y$ a homeomorphism, prove that for all $x\in X$ $f$ induces an homeomorphism between $X \setminus \lbrace x\rbrace$ and $Y \setminus \lbrace f(x) \rbrace$

I always had a idea to prove some thing,but in this case the unique idea that comes to my mind is use the definition of homeomorphism, the problem is ,that when i writte the  proof i use the fact that

since $f:X \to Y$ a homeomorphism then their restriction to a set  $X \setminus \lbrace x\rbrace$ will be continuous,and here i cant argue some thing. Any hint or comment was very helful.

Comment: Is $y=f(x){}{}$?

Comment: It's important that $y=f(x)$ here (that wasn't specified); it's not true for a general $y\in Y$.

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x\in X$, and for convenience let $\hat f=f\upharpoonright X\setminus\{x\}$. Since $f$ is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$, it’s clear that $\hat f$ is a bijection from $X\setminus\{x\}$ to $Y\setminus\{f(x)\}$. Let $U$ be an open set in $X\setminus\{x\}$; then there is an open $V\subseteq X$ such that $U=V\setminus\{x\}$. Then

$$\hat f[U]=f[V\setminus\{x\}]=f[V]\setminus\{f(x)\}\,,$$

and $f[V]$ is open in $Y$, so $\hat f[U]$ is open in $Y\setminus\{f(x)\}$. Now use a very similar argument to show that if $U$ is open in $Y\setminus\{f(x)\}$, then $\hat f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X\setminus\{x\}$.